# Most efficient way to retrieve a timer?

Tags: c++, time

I've never actually worked with timers before but I need one for my current project.

So this might be a silly question: but what's the 'normal' way to retrieve a timer for a game, and is there a better/more efficient way?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you mean by "timer"? Do you just want to measure elapsed time? At what sort of resolution?

Comment: What compiler/platform are you using?

Comment: @Mr. TAMER Default Visual Studio compiler and Windows as OS. 
I'm not sure what you mean by resolution. I suppose I need elapsed time, since I want to implement a max fps rate and get the time elapsed since the last Render and Update

Comment: @xcrypt: You are using the .NET libraries, is that right?

Comment: @Mr. TAMER I'm not sure actually, just the default ones? Like std, stl, windows.h, etc. I also use DirectX libs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you may want the time elapsed, and it might be so little, you might need to use the `clock()` function defined in `time.h`.

Here what I found about it in the MSDN Library:

---

Calculates the wall-clock time used by the calling process.

```
clock_t clock( void );
```

**Return Value**

The elapsed wall-clock time since the start of the process (elapsed time in seconds times CLOCKS_PER_SEC). If the amount of elapsed time is unavailable, the function returns –1, cast as a clock_t.

**Remarks**

The clock function tells how much time the calling process has used. A timer tick is approximately equal to 1/CLOCKS_PER_SEC second. In versions of Microsoft C before 6.0, the CLOCKS_PER_SEC constant was called CLK_TCK.

**Example:**
    // crt_clock.c
    // This example prompts for how long
    // the program is to run and then continuously
    // displays the elapsed time for that period.
    //

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void sleep( clock_t wait );

int main( void )
{
   long    i = 6000000L;
   clock_t start, finish;
   double  duration;

   // Delay for a specified time.
   printf( "Delay for three seconds\n" );
   sleep( (clock_t)3 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC );
   printf( "Done!\n" );

   // Measure the duration of an event.
   printf( "Time to do %ld empty loops is ", i );
   start = clock();
   while( i-- ) 
      ;
   finish = clock();
   duration = (double)(finish - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   printf( "%2.1f seconds\n", duration );
}

// Pauses for a specified number of milliseconds.
void sleep( clock_t wait )
{
   clock_t goal;
   goal = wait + clock();
   while( goal > clock() )
      ;
}
```

**Output**

```
Delay for three seconds
Done!
Time to do 6000000 empty loops is 0.1 seconds
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  clock computes the processor time consumed by the process.  look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/

Answer (score 1):

If you want cross-platform and performant time library, use [boost::date_time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/date_time.html). For timers, just get current time, and substract it from the next reading (they have operators for computing time difference etc, the code is readable).

Current time is read using [boost::posix_time::microsecond_clock::universal_time()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html) and stored in the `ptime` struct. (the `posix_` does not refer to that it is available only on POSIX systems; it only indicates that it is modeled after POSIX time concepts).

Comment: "Win32 systems often do not achieve microsecond resolution via this API." ?

Comment: @xcrypt: do you need microsecond precision for measuring FPS?

Comment: @xcrypt: If you use the .NET Libraries, you can easily achieve microsecond percision with the `DateTime` class

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C++ on windows you will want to use QueryPerformanceCounter/QueryPerformanceFrequency

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905(v=vs.85).aspx

If you are on linux check out clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME)

http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime

the clock() suggestion is incorrect as it is time used in the process.  since there is a loop his function will end up begin correct, but if you block then this will not work.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock